# How to format a string passing a constant variable as length width?

Tags: java, string, string-formatting

I'm learning Java so maybe this is a silly question, but here it is. I know that a `String` variable can be formatted in java using the `.format` method:

```
String.format("|%20s|", "Hello world");

>>|         Hello world|
```

But how can i specify the width using a variable? I.e, instead of typing the litteral '20':

```
String.format("|%MY_VARs|", "Hello world"); //<-- how to put MY_VAR inside?
```

Comment: What about `String.format(String.format("|%%%ds|", myVar), "Hello world");`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the following `String.format("|%" + MY_VARs +"s|", "Hello world");`

Comment: Thanks! A simple and elegant solution

Answer (score 1):

```
String format = String.format("|%%%d|", YOUR_VAR);
String formatted = String.format(format, "hello world");
```

Comment: |%%d| must be |%%%ds|

Comment: @mrmcwolf yes thanks, I was bound to mess up the escaping

Comment: +1 for the good solution. However, I accepted the @Freddie_Wilson's solution since yours required two lines of code and it's less intuitive

Answer (score 0):

Example of formatting:

```
int age = 19;
String name = "Dinh";
System.out.println(String.format("My name is %s and I am %s years old", name, age));
```

Should print > 'My name is Dinh and I am 19 years old'

```
String formatted = String.format(String.format("|%%d|", YOUR_VAR), "hello world");
```

You can also take a look at one of these articles:

https://dzone.com/articles/javaone-2017-day-1-keynote-notes-and-thoughts

https://www.dotnetperls.com/format-java